# AngularJS filter day

Tags: angularjs

I am building a Motivational Quote of the day app with AngularJS. The current day (or day number of the month ie: 1st of Jan) should pull Quote ID 1.
I have been getting some help with adding a day filter so the script pulls the quote from the DB according to the current day, but the day filter does not pull the correct quote id.

In app.js I have:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('TimeCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http, $timeout) {
  $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){

     $scope.quote = data;
     console.log($scope.quote);
  });
   $scope.dayNumber = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'd');
   console.log(  $scope.dayNumber );

});
```

In the View I have:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>require moment</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TimeCtrl">
  <p>
    {{dayNumber}} <br />
    {{"id is: " +quote[dayNumber].id + ": " +quote[dayNumber].quote}}<br />

---==--------==------<br />
   {{quote}}<br />

    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And in the getQuotes.php I have:

```
<?php
include('../includes/config.php');

$query="select id,quote from quotes order by id desc";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}

//start arr at key 1 instead of starting at 0
$arr = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr));

//sort obj to be in order
sort($arr);

# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response;

?>
```

At present, I have set my computer date to January the 1st 2015, so on the first line of the below screenshot, the `1` is the 1st day of January. And below this, the filter is pulling quote id 2 instead of pulling quote id 1

The rendered output is:
[image]

*** UPDATE 1 ****

after commenting out the array key to start at 1 and after commenting out the sort() function in the getQuotes.php, I have now noticed that no matter what the sort is like, the script alway take the last key/value from the db.

```
//start arr at key 1 instead of starting at 0
//$arr = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr));

//sort obj to be in order
//sort($arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because array indices start from 0. quote[1] will be the second element.

Comment: thanks but that did not work, commented out: //$arr = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr)); The script only get the last key/value in this array/JSON object

Comment: Okay, my bad, could you print out the array contents before sending it in PHP, and after receiving it in angular, and add them to the question?

Comment: Actually, no, I can see that you array index starts at 0 in javascript, there is no empty elements. Try changing to quote[dayNumber - 1] .

Comment: Yes, it works :) Thank you for your help Juunas. Anyone who would know as to why this works, please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, in your array in javascript, the first element is at index 0. So array[0] accesses the first element. In your code you attempt to access the first element with index 1. So instead it returns the second element. Even though you attempted to change the indices in PHP, I can still see that the array in javascript starts at index 0, as there is no empty element before the day 1 element. Does this make sense? Could you also mark my answer as accepted? :)